# preg_match - using an array of patterns - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have and array of text and an array of patterns.  I am trying to search each element in the array of text for all the patterns in the array of patterns.  However I am getting the error below and I do not understand where i am going wrong.

```
$participantVcRoomName = '/PR GMVC RP K GRAY/i';
$sipURI = '/+13135539892/i';
$row = '¤¤AdhocCallAdded¤¤+13135539892@11.198.0.54';
$row2 = '¤¤SentMessageToSystem¤¤The conference was extended, the new end time 
is: 10:45 AM¤¤PR GMVC RP K GRAY';
$row3 = '¤¤ConferenceEndTimeChanged¤¤09/13/2017 15:30:00 -05:00¤¤09/13/2017 
 10:30:00 -05:00';

$arrayDescp = [$row, $row2, $row3];
$arrayPatterns = [$participantVcRoomName, $sipURI];

foreach($arrayDescp  as $target){

    foreach($arrayPatterns as $aPattern) {

        $match = preg_match($aPattern, $target);
        if($match){
            echo 'match<br>';
        }else{
            echo 'no match<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Error message:

> `preg_match()`: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` is a special character in a regex, a quantifier meaning 1 or more. And as you don't have any character (-set) before that quantifier - it's the first entity in your regular expression, after the delimiter - you get that error.

If you want to match a litteral `+`, you need to escape it:

```
$sipURI = '/\+13135539892/i';
            ^^ a literal `+`
```

[An example](https://eval.in/897214).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying an index in your array to check. Replace your code with the following:

```
$participantVcRoomName = '/PR GMVC RP K GRAY/i';
$sipURI = '/+13135539892/i';
$row = '¤¤AdhocCallAdded¤¤+13135539892@11.198.0.54';
 $row2 = '¤¤SentMessageToSystem¤¤The conference was extended, the new end 
 time 
 is: 10:45 AM¤¤PR GMVC RP K GRAY';
 $row3 = '¤¤ConferenceEndTimeChanged¤¤09/13/2017 15:30:00 -05:00¤¤09/13/2017 
 10:30:00 -05:00';

 $arrayDescp = [$row, $row2, $row3];
 $arrayPatterns = [$participantVcRoomName, $sipURI];
 $t=0;
 foreach($arrayDescp  as $target){

 foreach($arrayPatterns as $aPattern){

   $match = preg_match($aPattern, $target[$t]);
   if($match){
      echo 'match<br>';
   }else{
    echo 'no match<br>';
      }

   }
 $t++;
}
```